# Show that a series of functions converges (uniformly)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Let $(f_n)_{n \geq1}$ be a sequence of functions defined by $f_n:
>  \mathbb{R}_0 \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} \quad
>  \quad x \in[n-1,n) \setminus\{0\}\\0 \quad \quad
>  \mathrm{else}\end{cases}$
>
> Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converge? Does it converge uniformly?

For $x \in \mathbb{R}_0: f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x \quad \quad n = \lfloor{x+1}\rfloor \\0\quad\quad \mathrm{else}\end{cases}$

Hence, for every fixed $x$, the series the sequence $f_n(x)$ is only non zero in one point, and hence the series $\sum_{n}f_n(x)$ is convergent in any point $x$. Hence, the series of functions $\sum f_n$ is pointwise convergent.

However, I have trouble to prove it is (not) uniformly convergent. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you find the supremum of $   \sum_{m\geq n} f_m$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb R_0$?

Comment: Real numbers without zero

Comment: Notice that this construction generalizes for $f\in C_0$, i.e. functions that vanish at infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: set $g_n(x):=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)$. Now observe that $f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)=1/x$, that is, $(g_k(x))_{k\in\Bbb N}\to f(x)$ pointwise.

Also observe that $$\|g_n-f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)-f(x)\right|=\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)\right|=1/n$$

Comment: I don't see how the last equality you wrote follows. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: this is just a hint, it is supposed that you must elaborate it, not me. Just use the definition of $f_k$ to see what function is  defined by $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)$, after take the supremum.

Comment: start observing what function is defined by $f_{n+1}+f_{n+2}$, then you will see easily what is $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)$